# How do I make something look like a tab after it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so the title may not be the best way to describe what i am trying to do, but i am not sure quite how to phrase it.

To start of (when the page loads) there are 20 'tiles' which serve as buttons on a page. They are divs. The 5 on top are larger and the rest of the rows are the same size. 
[image]

Once one of the buttons is clicked, i want a div to show under the row of the button that is clicked. I know how to do this part using jquery toggle. Here is an example of what i will want it to look like once a button is clicked. 
[image]

You can see in the drawing how i want it to sort of look like a tab once it is clicked. I am having trouble thinking of how i am going to add the part that ties the button div into the div that is toggled in the middle of the rows. This part:
[image]

I sort of thought that i could make 5 images, one for each column of buttons, that has that little part of background color, and toggle the image as well. I believe that there is a better way to do this so i am looking for a steer in the right direction. I have had some trouble searching for something like this as I dont really know what to call it so i thought i would come here for help. Thanks!

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I didn't even think of actually using tabs.. I am just worried about using something like that because making it look exactly how i want it to might me tricky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would increase the `height` of the tile when it is clicked (so that it expands down from the upper red line to the lower red line shown in the last image).

It can all be done just with CSS (using the checkbox hack in the same way I made [**this div**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3157489) to increase its height) or with JavaScript (if you want reliable behaviour for IE8 and especially IE7).

Comment: And then just have the z coordinate of the toggling div higher so its on top.. so simple but sounds so effective.. thank you

Comment: thanks! just got this working.. added some animations and it looks exactly how i had hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Like this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/ph8vY/